# WPF: Delete white lines between two Shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

If I render two rectangles on a canvas there is a small white line between them. Why? And how can I remove it?

Code:

```
var r = new Rectangle {Width = 100, Height = 100, Fill = Brushes.Black};
MyCanvas.Children.Add(r);
Canvas.SetLeft(r, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(r, 0);
var r2 = new Rectangle {Width = 100, Height = 100, Fill = Brushes.Black};
MyCanvas.Children.Add(r2);
Canvas.SetLeft(r2, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(r2, 0);
```

I already tried to set the stroke to "transparent".

[image]

Comment: what is the width and height of r1 ?

Comment: assuming the height and width of r1 is 100. It looks to be fine. unless there are other WPF Xaml elements on that is causing this .

Comment: I created an empty project, added a `Canvas` to the main window, and then copy/pasted your exact code into the constructor. I don't see any line between the rectangles like you show. There must be something different in your project that's causing it. Try making a blank project to test it yourself.

Comment: I also tried this on a project (.NET Framework) and looks perfect on mine. Potentially an operating system thing? Are you using .NET Standard or .NET Core?

Comment: This is probably anti-aliasing you're seeing. It will behave differently on different machines due to subtle differences in monitor, drivers etc. Settings you can try changing include: UIElement.UseLayoutRounding RenderOptions.EdgeMode and SnapsToDevicePixels

Comment: Andy's answer worked for me thanks